# Python 3.4.2 progressbar2 issue

Tags: python-3

The Pi was originally installed with Python 2.7

To install python 3.4.2, I did the following:

```
sudo apt install python3; mkdir ~/bin; ln -s /usr/bin/python3
 ~/bin/python
```

which Python:

```
/home/pi/bin/python
```

To revert Python 2.7:

```
rm ~/bin/python
```

which Python

```
/usr/bin/python
```

If I am in Python 3.4.2:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python --version
Python 3.4.2

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install progressbar2

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): progressbar2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/progressbar2-3.34.3-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-utils>=2.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_utils-2.2.0-py2.7.egg (from progressbar2)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from python-utils>=2.1.0->progressbar2)
Cleaning up...
```

The problem is `progressbar2` is installed on Python 2.7.

How do I install `progressbar2` for Python 3.4.2?

Answer (score 1):

If the package is available in Raspbian you should use that repository in preference to the pip repository.

If you must use pip then use the **pip3** command to install for Python 3.

Comment: I tried what you suggested>

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3 install progressbar2
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting progressbar2
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/progressbar2/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement progressbar2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for progressbar2
pi@raspberrypi:~ $

Comment: I tried pip3 install progressbar2
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available